# Custom Repository does not work

Tags: symfony, doctrine

Symfony 3.3, 
I do according to the documentation https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/repository.html

```
$entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$users = $entityManager->getRepository(Users::class)->findAllOrderedByName();
```

I get exception:

```
BadMethodCallException:
Undefined method 'findAllOrderedByName'. The method name must start with either findBy or findOneBy!

  at vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository.php:226
  at Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository->__call('findAllOrderedByName', array())
     (src\AppBundle\Controller\DefaultController.php:28)
  at Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository->findAllOrderedByName()
     (src\AppBundle\Controller\DefaultController.php:28)
  at AppBundle\Controller\DefaultController->indexAction(object(Request))
  at call_user_func_array(array(object(DefaultController), 'indexAction'), array(object(Request)))
     (var\cache\dev\classes.php:4453)
  at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(object(Request), 1)
     (var\cache\dev\classes.php:4408)
  at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(object(Request), 1, true)
     (vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel.php:171)
  at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->handle(object(Request))
     (web\app_dev.php:29)
```

Users entity:

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Users
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="users")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\UsersRepository")
 */
class Users
{
    ...
}
```

UsersRepository

```
namespace AppBundle\Repository;

use AppBundle\Entity\Users;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: Hett
 * Date: 21.07.2017
 * Time: 14:25
 */
class UsersRepository extends EntityRepository
{

    public function findAllOrderedByName()
    {
        return $this->getEntityManager()
            ->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select("u")
            ->from(Users::class, "u")
            ->orderBy("name")
            ->getQuery()
            ->getArrayResult();
    }
}
```

As I understand `$entityManager->getRepository(Users::class)` return default EntiryRepository. Why? What's my mistake?

UPD:  I tried to clear cache, but it has no effect:

```
Hett@Range MINGW64 /c/www/symfony (master)
$ ./bin/console  cache:clear

 // Clearing the cache for the dev environment with debug
 // true

 [WARNING] Calling cache:clear without the --no-warmup option is deprecated
           since version 3.3. Cache warmup should be done with the cache:warmup
           command instead.

 [OK] Cache for the "dev" environment (debug=true) was successfully cleared.


Hett@Range MINGW64 /c/www/symfony (master)
$ ./bin/console doctrine:cache:clear-metadata
Clearing ALL Metadata cache entries
Successfully deleted cache entries.
```

[image]

Comment: Typically it is an entity to repository mapping issue.  Make sure you don't have any old mapping files under Resources/config/doctrine.  Make sure you clear the cache.  On occasion, singing Hey Jude under a full moon helps as well.

Comment: @Cerad already tried, but it not resolve problem (I updated my post)

Comment: Do you have multiple Entity Managers? (for the sake of clarity :-))

Comment: Is the file called UsersRepository.php and it's located under the correct path? Maybe you have a typo or the file isn't in the correct path.

Comment: @gp_sflover I think no... i have clear default project

Comment: @sh4 i updated question and add files tree

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have auto-generated file
`src/AppBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/Users.orm.yml`
As I understand .yml configs rewrites annotations congiruation,
when I remove Users.org.yml or add line `repositoryClass: AppBundle\Repository\UsersRepository` - all work fine.
Which method is correct?

Comment: You can one or the other (yml or annotation) but not both.  If you like annotations then just remove the yml files.  If you are not fond of annotations then keep the yml files.  Your choice.